# No Maven: Generate from Maven Archetype command in VsCode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I've installed and configured **Maven 3.6.3** in Win10. Then the **Maven for java** extension in Vscode.
When I type `mvn -version`, it correctly showed the version message.

However, when I opened an empty folder and right click to create a maven project, there is no response from VsCode. There are 2 ways to create a Maven project, as the official doc says [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-build#_generate-project-from-maven-archetype).

But when I opened the Command Palette(*Ctrl + Shift + P*) and searched for the command **Maven: Generate from Maven Archetype**, there's no result.

What's wrong with this problem and how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the extension updates, but the docs keep the same.

I've installed [Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), which includes [Maven for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven), and there's indeed no command `Maven: Generate from Maven Archetype`, but we have **Maven: Create Maven Project**, so there are two ways to generate a Maven project:

1. From the Command Palette, select **Maven: Create Maven Project** and click your wanted archetype.
2. Right-click on a folder and select **Create Maven Project**.

[image]